# Request Header for Token + Email Authorization

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to use an API with token authorization.

In their documentation it says:

Every request should contain an Authorization header with the api credentials like this:
`Authorization: Token token="abc123", email="reseller@example.com"`

I'm unsure how exactly I need to set my headers, I have tried this

```
try {
  const res = await fetch("https://pokamax.com/apis/reseller/v1/orders", {
    method: "get",
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: 'Token token="mytoken", email="my@email.com',
      // Authorization: "Bearer mytoken"
    })
  });
  console.log("Res", res);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error", error);
}
```

But it won't work. How do I need to set my headers?

Comment: Why the Authorization header should contain the email?
What API are you using? If it's something developed by you, the code would be helpful

Comment: @PabloCordero Not my API. Here are some docs: https://pokamax.com/docs/Reseller-Api-Documentation-V1-EN.pdf but they are not really clear to me and can't find anything else

Comment: Which status code do you receive?

Comment: @PabloCordero I only get `Failed to fetch`, no status code

Comment: There's a typo in your code: `'Token token="mytoken", email="my@email.com'` -> `'Token token="mytoken", email="my@email.com"'`

Answer (score 1):

According with [1] Authorization header must have the following structure:

```sh
Authorization: <type> <credentials>
```

`Token` and `email` are not allowed types on this header as MDN says [2]. I think the docs of the API doesn't give enough information about this. I think the email could be a separate custom header. I'm not sure this will work as I don't not how the API works but check if this work:

```js
try {
  const res = await fetch("https://pokamax.com/apis/reseller/v1/orders", {
    method: "get",
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: 'Bearer mytoken',
      email: 'my@email.com'
    })
  });
  console.log("Res", res);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error", error);
}
```

---

[1] - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

[2] - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#authentication_schemes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, because I can't read the original docs, but most headers would follow a format similar to:

```
headers: new Headers({ 
        Authorization: { 
             'Token': 'token="mytoken", email="my@email.com'' 
                       } 
                })
```

Give it a shot, maybe it'll work.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work either, thanks for the help though